# Is there a bug with the `switch ocg with mark on` key of the ocgx and ocgx2 packages?

Tags: ocgx2, ocgx

Indeed, with this key, visibility does not work properly.

I quote the manual:

> `/tikz/switch ocg with mark on={<ocg reference»}{<OCGs list> }` These
>   styles transform the current path or the current node in a link acting
>   as if it is produced by the macro `\switchocg` (the visibility status of
>   referenced OCGs in the list is reversed).
>
> A mark (currently a simple cross) is drawn over the current path or node in an OCG whose reference is ocg reference . The visibility status of this OCG will be reversed as those of the entire list.

Thus, the following two examples should work in the same way. However, only the second one with the `switchocg` key with the `status=invisible` leaves the rectangle invisible from the beginning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{%
  button on/.style={%
    draw,minimum size=5mm,
    line width=1pt,
    fill=blue!50,rounded corners,
    switch ocg with mark on={#1}{},
  },
}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[ocg={name=rect1,ref=rect1,status=invisible}]
\draw[fill=green!50](0,0)rectangle(2,1);
\end{scope}
\node[button on=rect1]at (-1.5,.5)(but){};
    \node[right=0 of but]{rect1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[ocg={name=rect2,ref=rect2,status=invisible}]
\draw[fill=green!50](0,0)rectangle(2,1);
\end{scope}
\node[draw,rounded corners,switch ocg=rect2] at (-1,.5) {rectangle};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `switch ocg with mark on` Ti*k*z style implicitly sets the PDF layer, whose ID is passed to it as its argument, to the visibility state ON.

In the document code listed in the question, the button is inserted *after* the `rectangle` shape which belongs to the same PDF layer as the button's cross-mark. With `ocgx2`, the layer visibility setting that comes last wins over previous settings. You can easily check this by swapping `rectangle` and the button:

Original code:

```
\begin{scope}[ocg={name=rect1,ref=rect1,status=invisible}] % layer `rect1' set to OFF,
\draw[fill=green!50](0,0)rectangle(2,1);
\end{scope}
\node[button on=rect1]at (-1.5,.5)(but){}; % but ON wins, as it comes last
```

For testing:

```
\node[button on=rect1] at (-1.5,.5)(but){}; % layer `rect1' set to ON,
\begin{scope}[ocg={name=rect1,ref=rect1,status=invisible}] % OFF wins, as desired
\draw[fill=green!50](0,0)rectangle(2,1);
\end{scope}
```

Answer (score 2):

The English and French manuals of the `ocgx` package do not indicate the same keys.

The French manual indicates the key

> /tikz/switch OCG with mark={< basename >}{< OCG list > }

This key is not indicated in the English manual which indicates two keys:

> /tikz/switch ocg with mark on={< ocg reference > }{< OCGs list > }
>
> /tikz/switch ocg with mark off={< ocg reference >}{< OCGs list > }

To ensure that the rectangle is not displayed by default at the beginning, we must use the `switch ocg with mark off` key.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{%
  button on/.style={%
    draw,minimum size=5mm,
    line width=1pt,
    fill=blue!50,rounded corners,
    switch ocg with mark off={#1}{},
  },
}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[ocg={name=rect1,ref=rect1}]
\draw[fill=green!50](0,0)rectangle(2,1);
\end{scope}
\node[button on=rect1]at (-1.5,.5)(but){};
    \node[right=0 of but]{rect1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[ocg={name=rect2,ref=rect2,status=invisible}]
\draw[fill=green!50](0,0)rectangle(2,1);
\end{scope}
\node[draw,rounded corners,switch ocg=rect2] at (-1,.5) {rectangle};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If **AlexG** *(ocgx2 maintainer)* and **Paul Gaborit** *(ocgx maintainer)* are kind enough to clarify this, I will gladly accept their answer.